Which operations on distributions respect MaxEnt property?
Seems like MaxEnt property for log-normal distribution follows directly from MaxEnt property of normal. So for any Y, such that f(Y) = X, if X is MaxEnt then Y is MaxEnt as well with constraints derived as well. Not sure if which conditions should be applied to f and if using direct function (like exp for log-normal would work).
My question is: what are other known results for operations on distributions producing MaxEnt distributions from other MaxEnt distributions?

Your linked Wikipedia article says that MaxEnt distributions all look like
$$p(x) \propto \exp\sum_j \lambda_j f_j(x)$$
where $f_j(x)$ are the constraints.
This means that if you take $Y=g(X)$ and also change the constraints to $g_j(y)=f_j(g^{-1}(y))$ you will get another MaxenT distribution.  So the Normal has $f_j$ being mean and variance of $X$ and the logNormal has $g_j$ being mean and variance of $X$, ie, mean and variance of $\log Y$.
So it works at least for any smooth $f$ with smooth inverse, but it may give you silly constraints.  For example, if you take $y = (x-7)^3$ you get a distribution that's MaXeNt subject to constraints on the mean and variance of the cube root of $Y+7$.

Perhaps you are interested in the books of David Blower. They can be downloaded from here: https://www.bayesinaction.nl/books-david-j-blower/
